# Solved | Unity SQLite conection unable to open database file

Tags: android, database, sqlite, unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity and SQLite.
I am doing an Android app, that should work offline. It is the first time I use Unity and SQLite.

I am just trying to connect to my SQLite database file, `TrilhoVerde.db`. I created it using SQLiteAdministrator. I created a database but is empty. I would create the necessary tables in the C# file (because of the foreign keys). This is the code I have:

```
private IDbConnection connection;
private IDbCommand command;
private IDataReader reader;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    Connection();
}

private void Connection()
{
    string dbFile = "URI=File:"+ Application.dataPath +"/Plugins/TrilhoVerde.db:";
    connection = (IDbConnection) new SqliteConnection(dbFile);
    connection.Open();

    command = connection.CreateCommand();

    string createTable = "select * from Avatar;";
    command.CommandText = createTable;
    reader = command.ExecuteReader();
}
```

But when I run it in Unity, I got this error:

> SqliteSyntaxException: unable to open database file
>   Mono.Data.SqliteClient.SqliteCommand.GetNextStatement (System.IntPtr pzStart, System.IntPtr& pzTail, System.IntPtr& pStmt) (at <9f65d62b5efa4334801a8fece4acee8a>:0)
>   Mono.Data.SqliteClient.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader (System.Data.CommandBehavior behavior, System.Boolean want_results, System.Int32& rows_affected) (at <9f65d62b5efa4334801a8fece4acee8a>:0)
>   Mono.Data.SqliteClient.SqliteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery () (at <9f65d62b5efa4334801a8fece4acee8a>:0)
>   carrega.Connection () (at Assets/scipts/carrega.cs:30)
>   carrega.Start () (at Assets/scipts/carrega.cs:17)

I was using the tutorials in these videos:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QtDtBvAyzOQ

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CtDSQkLdlZg

I think I did all the steps. I know that there are a lot of questions related to this matter, but so far none if them solved my problem. If something is missing to understand what I did and what is wrong, please tell me.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong.
And I'm sorry if this is something really simple, but, like I said, I am new to Unity and SQLite.

**UPDATE**

I created a new database file using another program and I commented the command part of the code. It now does not threw any error. Reversing that comment, error again.

The problem is in this specific line:

`reader = command.ExecuteReader();`

I also added the tables in database file, not in C#. Stil don't know what the problem is.

Comment: Do you use this code on the Android platform?

Comment: I'm not sure but change `URI=File:...` to `URI=file:...`.

Comment: I got the same error. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am really sorry to de ones that lost time on this, and I am embarrassed too. The name of the database file was wrong. I was supposed to TrilhoVerde.db, but I had TrilhoVerde.bd: in the script.